# Complete file changed git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am currently working with a Xamarin project, where all file references are put inside one project file. This file changes each time someone on our team adds or removes a file.

Now I have gotten a few conflicts in the last days, where my colleagues and I all add and remove files in the project. Git used to merge this file quite beautifully and it was usually only a matter of minutes before merge conflicts were resolved.

Now in the last few days, I have had to manually redo my changes, as git saw the project file as completely different, even though only a few lines changed.

The conflicts look like so:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
// The entire file on my branch
======= 
// The entire file on the master branch
>>>>>>> mobile
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Double check if line endings are the same and if you use tabs or spaces on both versions.

Comment: @divix yes they were line endings. Please submit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if line endings are the same and if you use tabs or spaces, or both on different versions.